# Find the indices corresponding to values oscillating around the minimum with matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, min

I have two arrays, and I am trying to find the indices corresponding to those oscillating around a minimum value. Below are two figures showing this behavior in the values of my arrays.

[image: full]
[image: zoom]

As you can see, some values are slightly lower than the rest, but I would still like to include them in the result since the difference is minimal.

Is there a way to use the `min` function to find the indices within a tolerance of a value? I've tried using `uniquetol` to find the actual values but I'm not sure how to apply it with what I need with min. I've only been able to find the indices of the absolute lowest values, which is only a small subset of all the ones I am considering.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up some tolerance to the `min`. Let's say `a' is one of your arrays:

```
tol = 0.001; % set this to proper value
minV = min(a); % find min
ind = find(a < minV+tol); % indices smaller than minV+tol
```

You may set `tol` to a percentage of `minV` if it makes more sense.